# How to apply new line bettwen paranthesis string?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to split player name in two lines, But no luck

```
cell.lblHomeTeam.text = "\(model.player_name!) \n  \(model.replaced_player_name!)"
```

**Current output**

```
Player1 \n Player2
```

**Required Output**

```
Player1
Player2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set

```
cell.lblHomeTeam.numberOfLines = 0
```

the wrapping also depend on how you set constraints , so it should be either a leading & fixed width `or` a trailing & fixed width  `or` leading & trailing